# Sorting values in for plotting in R

Tags: r, sorting, graph, plot

I have a data that looks like this:

```
> print(dat)
    cutoff  tp    fp
1    0.6    414 45701
2    0.7    172 16820
3    0.8    51  4326
4    0.9    49  3727
5    1.0    0     0
```

I want to plot them in reverse-order from smallest `dat$tp` to largest.
However this code plot them in order like above (i.e. largest to smallest) instead.

```
> fp_max <- max(dat$fp);
> tp_max <- max(dat$tp);
> op <- par(xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
> plot(tp ~ fp, data = dat, xlim = c(0,fp_max),ylim = c(0,tp_max), type = "n")
> with(dat, lines(c(0, fp, fp_max), c(0, tp, tp_max),  lty=1, type = "l",  col = "black"))
> lines( par()$usr[1:2], par()$usr[3:4], col="red" )
```

How can I modify the code above to address the problem?

Of course, the x-axis & y-axis coordinates should be from smallest to largest value

The following shows the result of my current code. 
[image: Figure]

Notice that the line started at 0,0 and it 'goes back' to 0 again. 
we want to avoid it going back to 0.

Comment: I'm confused as to the output you want - it doesn't matter what order the rows are in, the `(fp,tp)` plot will always look like a diagonal line from (0,0) upwards to the right? e.g. It doesn't matter what order you draw (0,0) and (1,1) on a plot; the line will still look the same.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: I updated the OP with figure. Does it clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ahh, I understand.

It's because `lines` draws lines between the points in the order they are given.

There are a few ways you could get around this:

1. do `type='l'` in your `plot` command and then `with(dat,lines(...))` is not necessary:

   ```
   # can also do the col='black',lty=1 in here.
   plot(tp ~ fp, data = dat, xlim = c(0,fp_max),ylim = c(0,tp_max), type = "l")
   ```

   Note that *by definition* of your `fp_max` and `tp_max`, you will include the point `(fp_max,tp_max)` already. And as long as you have a row with `(0,0)` for `tp` and `fp` in `dat`, you'll also get the `(0,0)` point.
2. Sort `dat$tp` and use that to sort `dat$fp` too:

   ```
   plot(tp ~ fp, ..., type='n')
   # sort dat$tp
   obj <- sort(dat$fp,index.return=T)
   # use obj$x as tp and obj$ix to sort dat$fp prior to plotting
   with(dat, 
        lines(c(0, obj$x, fp_max), c(0, tp[obj$ix], tp_max),  
              lty=1, type = "l",  col = "black"))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Get order of rows
idx <- order(dat$tp)

#Select data in sorted order
sorted <- dat[idx,]
```